# Jade helper for FontAwesome

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I want to write some helper for `FontAwesome` in `jade` template in `Express.js`, so I did in `app.js`:

```
app.locals.icon = function(icon){ return '<i class="fa fa-' + icon + '"></i>'; };
```

and called in template:

```
block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  = icon('users')
```

however it returns me escaped HTML code. What is a good practise for writing this kind of helpers ? How to return raw HTML ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try with != operator**

```
 != icon('users')
```

Refrence from http://jade-lang.com/

*Unescaped buffered code starts with != and outputs the result of evaluating the JavaScript expression in the template. This does not do any escaping, so is not safe for user input.*

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you ! Can I also ask you, what whould be the best place to put in it my custom Jade helper ?

Comment: @hsz if that helper is belong to 1 jade file, i would put it inside the jade. Put this line to jade: "- fa = function (icon) {...}". You can use it: != fa('user')